# Generate HTML Report after running django unit testing testcases

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing

I am newbie to djnago and python, I want to generate the report of testcases run by djnago  and send in mail to team.

Please help me

Comment: See coverage - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/advanced/#integration-with-coverage-py

Answer (score 0):

Django coverage package make a html file.
If you have multiple settings for your project you should run tests for each setting then combine result with (coverage combine) command then you can get a html file and attach the file in email even you can render result like django html templates.
With python subproccess you can run shell command in django.